# Custom TabBar Design iOS

Tags: ios, swift, layer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

[image]

Guys I want this tabBar for my application but don't know how to make this style TabBar. I know some basic knowledge about UIBezierPath class and shaplayer etc but I can't handle controlpoints of UIBezierPath method addCurve. Please do help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you search for similar solutions?

Comment: Yes I did, But I can't understand the concept of add curve method and can't handle the controlpoint parameter of that.

Comment: Here is an example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59091488/6057764 which you can use as a reference, to get started.

Comment: Update your question with what you’ve tried and what you’re stuck with.  Show us your progress